Milchig and fleishig keilim
If one has 2 pareve foods, one having been cooked in a fleishig pot and the other cooked in a milchig pot, may the 2 foods be eaten together?

duplicate of Pareves made on dairy dishes and pareves made on meat dishes in the same meal ?

Welcome to MiYodeya Ron and thanks for this first question. Your question might be closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

If either of the pots weren't used in the last 24 hours and were clean it is muttar. If they were both used in the last 24 hours for Hot Dairy and Meat (respectively): If @Ron is of Sfardi descent, it's muttar SA YD 95.2. According to Ashkenazi p'sak in this scenario it should also be muttar as they are each a Nat Bar Nat of Hetter(See Shach 5 ibid)

@y_g if you answer already then you might want to mention charif foods
